# SQL Server 2012 Avoiding Index Scan for Aggregate?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, aggregate-functions

I have a large select statement, with an index scan taking 83% of the time, and it takes many seconds to return when there are 700k rows. I made a subset of it here:

```
set nocount on
create table #scanme ( lookid int identity primary key , stateid tinyint )
create nonclustered index scanstateid on #scanme (stateid) where stateid in ( 0 )
go
insert into #scanme values ( 0 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 0 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 0 )
go
insert into #scanme values ( 0 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 0 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 0 )
go
insert into #scanme values ( 0 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 0 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 0 )
go
insert into #scanme values ( 0 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 0 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 1 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 2 ) ; insert into #scanme values ( 0 )
go
select 
    sum( case when stateid=0 then 1 else 0 end ) as notdone
  , sum( case when stateid=1 then 1 else 0 end ) as doneok
  , sum( case when stateid=2 then 1 else 0 end ) as doneerrors
from
  #scanme
```

If you run this in SSMS right now you will not see the same plan I am getting, the DML above is just to illustrate where my problem is. With 700k rows, the sum requirement is apparently causing an index scan as MSSQL looks at every stateid and adds it up.

Can anyone recommend a different index (or how to alter my select) that would make this query return quickly?

Thanks.

Comment: First glance, get rid of the filter in the scanstateid index. Currently, scanstateid can only be used when the predicate is "WHERE stateid = 0".

Comment: The filtered index is used for other queries. But you got me thinking, and I created additional filtered indexes and moved things around a bit. Query time went from 40 seconds on my real data to 2 seconds in SSMS. I would prefer 0 seconds, but I'll live with 2 at this point. Thanks!